# Add image button in draggable DIV & toggle image source on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, position, draggable

I have draggable DIV's. An image is appended in these DIV's. When mouse is over DIV' s, the `opacity` of the image is changed to `1`. When mouse is out, image gets opacity `0`.

1. On Click I want to change image from `close_1.jpg` to image `close_2.jpg` - and stop dragging that DIV.
2. I want to change position of the image to the left + top side. 5px upper DIV.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/mevbF/14/)

CSS

```
div {
      width:200px;
      padding:10px;
      border: 2px solid #fff;
      cursor: pointer;
      background: #ccc;
}
```

HTML

```
<img class="close" src="http://ynternet.sk/test2/close_1.jpg" />
   <div>Demo 1 Div </div>
   <div>Demo 2 Div </div>
   <div>Demo 3 Div </div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').append( $("img.close").css("opacity", "0" ));
  $('div').find('img.close').css("paddingLeft", "20px");
  $('div').mouseover(function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({borderColor: "#aaa" }, "slow");
      $(this).find('img.close').css("opacity", "1");
  }).mouseout(function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({borderColor: "#fff" }, "slow");
      $(this).find('img.close').css("opacity", "0");
  })
  $('div').draggable({ grid: [ 10,10 ] });
});
```

Comment: example > http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/mevbF/18/

Comment: what you mean by 5px upper DIV?

Comment: @Patrik - How is a style declaration an acceptable answer for this question?

Comment: @j08691 - In my last answer - there is final solution and example http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/nfRjk/6/. Everything is working fine :]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this will stop the drag and change the image:

```
$('div img').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'http://ynternet.sk/test2/close_2.jpg').parent().draggable("destroy");
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mevbF/19/)**.

I'm just not clear on what you meant in #2 by "5px upper DIV".

Comment: thank you, it works fine, but... I want to turn it back by mouse click, and also change IMG. :]

Answer (score 1):

I guess this might solve the -5px

```
div img.close {
 position: absolute;
 float: left;
 top: -15px; 
 right: 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mevbF/23/